# Error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception en Flutter

Tags: flutter

me encuentro con el siguiente error cuando trato de emular mi aplicación.
No consigo solventarlo con la información que recibo en el mensaje de error, no encuentro el parámetro que me sugiere en el Build.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update C:\Users\Nath\Desktop\Dev\ads\android\build.gradle:
ext.kotlin_version = ''
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: **Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.**... ¿Intentaste lo que te dice el mensaje que le sigue? Además, ¿qué te dice el stacktrace? Hay que leer los mensajes :)

Answer (score 0):

Entra al enlace que te marca el error:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions

Ahí revisa la última versión de kotlin! Ahorita me esta marcando que es la 1.6.10

En tu proyecto te vas a dirigir a android>build.gradle

Solo cambia la versión en el ext.kotlin_version de tal manera que te quede de la siguiente forma:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```